# Script Appends Extension Twice

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am running a quick bash script that will convert any .mov files to .mp4.  This works great 99% of the time, but sometimes I hit a snare and I get an error of:

> the file /home/jgeoffrey/Documents/HomeMovie/Test/year1video.mov.mov No such file or directory

As you can see the file extension is for some reason added twice to the end of the file?  If I navigate to the actual directory that is not the case, it is only there one time.

What is causing this to occur and how do I fix?  Below is script:

```
#Scanning Documents for any mov files
for f in $(find /home/jgeoffrey/Documents -type f -name "*.mov");
do
 #checking if a .mp4 exists
 mp4=${f%.mov}.mp4  
 #if no .mp4 exist convert the file
 if ! lsof $f && [ ! -e "$mp4" ];
 then
    #Converting the file to .mp4
    avconv -i $f.mov -codec copy $f.mp4
 fi
done
```

Comment: How come it works 99% of the time? the variable `$f` already contains the `.mov` file and with `avconf` you are again doing `$f.mov` ..

Comment: @heemayl - ah, you are 100% accurate there.  When I scanned the dir, I saw .mp4 files in there and assumed it was bc they were successfully converted.  In actuality that was the original formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `find` command:

```
find /home/jgeoffrey/Documents -type f -name "*.mov"
```

you are finding and iterating over `.mov` files using variable `f`. So the value of variable `$f` already contains `.mov` file. For example, say one of the files is `foo.mov`.

Again, in `avconf` you have used the input file as `$f.mov`, so the filename becomes

```
foo.mov.mov
```

This is exactly what the error says:

> year1video.**mov.mov**: No such file or directory

So you need:

```
avconv -i "$f" -codec copy "$mp4"
```

as `$mp4` already contains the file name with `.mov` stripped and `.mp4` added.

Also quote your variable containing filenames, otherwise it will fail in case of filenames with whitespaces.

Also while looping over a newline separated list of files, use `while`, instead of `for`:

```
find .... | while IFS= read -r f; do .....
```